# What is the minimum age to play chess in the senior category?

Tags: senior-chess

A senior chess tournament for selection of nationals is happening in our state. I would like to play. What age do I have to be to play in the different senior categories?

Answer (score 2):

FIDE has 2 senior age categories - over 50 and over 65. Most national federations will follow FIDE's lead.

Note that over 50 means that you will be at least 50 years old on the 31st December of that year. So, for over 50 tournaments this year you need to have been born in 1968 or earlier. The reason FIDE do it this way is that they publish your year of birth but not your exact date of birth (for privacy reasons). This information allows organizers to establish whether or not you are eligible.